# Mac Address RegEx to filter out Bad Macs

Tags: regex, pcre, mac-address

I have a 3rd party app that has a MAC address field that I can only apply a RegEx to for data validation. I have a RegEx that works to validate length, hex, and dashes/colons. My stumbling block is trying to prevent an entry of all the same character, all 0's, all 1's etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
/^(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}([-:]{0,1}))(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\1){4}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}$/
```

Comment: Having all identical digits is unlikely, but not an invalid MAC address.

Comment: Could you define clearly what you consider to be "bad MAC addresses" and "good MAC addresses"?

Comment: Do you realize that all 1's is a MAC broadcast address?  You might also want to start by verifying the OUI (first 6 hex digits) which is the manufacturer that issued the address.

Comment: A bad mac in my case would be one that a person would enter to to just satisfy the requirement of one being entered. The issue I faced was all 0s but I wanted to go beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PCRE you can use a negative lookahead to disallow some specific patterns.

```
/^(?!(.)\1(?:[-:]?\1\1)+$)[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}([-:]?)(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\2){4}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}$/
```

Notice that I also refactored your regex slightly.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a open parenthesis "(" right before the second [A-Fa-f0-9]? If so, I thinks this solves my problem.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that; fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

All the parts match the same character class. You could also start the pattern with a negative lookahead `(?!.*([A-Fa-f0-9])\1)` to check if there are no 2 the same characters following using another backreference.

Then your current backreference will increment from `\1` to `\2`

```
^(?!.*([A-Fa-f0-9])\1)(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}([-:]?))(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\2){4}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}$
```

[Regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/QaOvxh/1)

Comment: This rejects an address where two digits in the same group are identical, which is quite likely way too aggressive. The OP is looking to reject aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa etc where *all* the digits are identical.